# Text-overflow: ellipsis not working, despite using all necessary css prerequisites

Tags: html, css, overflow

I can't figure out why is the text overflow ellipsis property not working here...

HTML:

```
<div class='overflowTest'>
   Long long long long long long text
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.overflowTest {
   overflow: hidden; 
   white-space: no-wrap; 
   text-overflow: ellipsis; 
   background-color: red; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 12px; 
   -moz-border-radius: 12px; 
   border-radius: 12px; 
   margin:4px; 
   padding:4px; 
   width: 46%; 
   height:30px; 
   font-size: 12px; 
   padding-top:7px; 
   font-style: normal; 
   float: left; 
}
```

It has overflow set to hidden, white-space to no-wrap, and text-overflow to ellipsis, it also has a given width(tried changing that from percentage to fixed number, still doesn't work), what am I missing?

Here's also a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9xhrs2nj/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no hyphen in `nowrap`.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/tef5ywr2/)

It should be:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

rather than:

```
white-space: no-wrap;
```

Comment: @AdamBaranyai I don't think so. There are inconsistencies in CSS.. `white-space` has a hyphen.. `inline-block` has a hyphen, but `nowrap` doesn't? You can always look in the developer tool to see if a property/value isn't being applied though.